# Replace pipe-shellscript with C-program

Tags: c, bash, pipe

I have the following Bash script:

`cat | command1 | command2 | command3`

The commands never change.

For performance reasons, I want to replace it with a small C-program, that runs the commands and creates and assings the pipes accordingly.

Is there a way to do that in C?

Comment: I'm a little bit doubt about the performance gain you can get through C.

Comment: @JermaineXu Well, I don't have doubts about the performance gain. I'm actually sure that it's nonexistent.

Comment: What programming language they use to write `bash`? You have three guesses.

Comment: If `cat` reads only one file, you can remove it and redirect input for the `command` from that file. That might give you higher performance boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~jglenn/702/S2005/Examples/twopipes.c) that does pretty much this.

There is no performance benefit for the processing itself, just a couple of milliseconds in initialization. Obviously we don't know the context in which you're doing this, but just using `dash` instead of `bash` would probably have gotten you 80% of those milliseconds from a single character change in your `#!`

Comment: I do care about latency, so the initialization is important for me.

Answer (score 5):

As others said, you probably won't get a significant performance benefit.
It's reasonable to assume that the commands you run take most of the time, not the shell script gluing them together, so even if the glue becomes faster, it will change almost nothing.

Having said that, if you want to do it, you should use the `fork()`, `pipe`, `dup2()` and `exec()` functions.
`fork` will give you multiple processes.
`pipe` will give you a pair of file descriptors - what you write into one, you can read from the other.
`dup2` can be used to change file descriptor numbers. You can take one side of a pipe and make it become file descriptor 1 (stdout) in one process, and the other side you'll make file descriptor 0 (stdin) in another (don't forget to close the normal stdin, stdout first).
`exec` (or one of its variants) will be used to execute the programs.

There are lots of details to fill in. Have fun.